# Unit test in complex app with AngularJS: karma, jasmine, BUT "require is not defined" in textAngular-rangy.min.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We have built a complex web app with AngularJS. Now we need to add some unit tests (OK, you can say, this is too late, but, please, give it a try) and we use Grunt, Jasmine and Karma for this.

Our package.json contains these lines:

```
{ 
    "devDependencies": [
        "grunt-html2js": "0.3.2",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
        "karma": "0.13.10",
        "karma-jasmine": "0.3.6",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.0",
        "karma-firefox-launcher": "0.1.6",
        "grunt-karma": "0.12.1",
    ]
}
```

Our gruntFile.js:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html2js');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
```

Our Karma config file **contains**:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated Sep 2015

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    //more options
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 4000,
    client: {
       captureConsole: true
    },

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '../../',

    //no plugins!

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [

        { 'pattern': 'dist/js/libs.js', included: true, served: true },
        // some more
        'test/unit/**/*.spec.js'
    ],

    // more stuff

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

---

This runs, we have created a suitable grunt task for it. Karma starts a server, a web browser (Chrome) and starts testing. I'd guessed, it loads the files in the `<head>` of the index.html (or smth. similar), which Chrome browses. It turned out, that the whole stuff apparently happens in an `<iframe>` in that web-page. Anyway.

Karma now stops working while claiming, that `"require is not defined"`. This required can be found in our libs.js, which includes textAngular-rangy.min.js (created by `bower` from textAngular, version 1.4.1). This awesome library is made for browsers or node.js, so I guess it checks, whether `window` is there and switches to `require` (node mode), if not. *This should work fine in the instance of Chrome, which Karma starts.*

---

Does anybody has an idea, why not and has a suggestion for a workaround?

There [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912738/angularjs-jasmine-karma-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117092/jasmine-tests-in-karma-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) SO-Questions, but, basically, adding the `require` module for Karma makes things even worse.

Comment: Do you actually need the `textAngular` module in your unit tests? I ended up simply mocking away the entire module, thus avoiding the dependency on rangy.

Comment: I ended up using the unminified version of rangy (in general) and had the guess, that there might be a  [bug in karma-runner](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1598).